# Prove something that is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

The question states

If g(x) is differentiable, then for any positive integer $n$, $(g(x))^n$ is differentiable and  $\frac d{dx}$$(g(x))^n=(g(x))^{n-1}g'(x). $ Where does the continuity of g enter your argument.

Alright, so I know that since g(x) is differentiable, then it is continuous everywhere.  I also know that $g'(x)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$.  I need to show that ($(g(x))^n$)=$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)^n-g(a)^n}{x-a}$.  I also know that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)^n-g(a)^n}{x-a}$=$(g(x))^{n-1}+(g(x))^{n-2}a+…+g(x)a^{n-2}+a^{n-1}.$

I need some help now.  What is my next step, am I going in the right direction. Help.

Comment: If you know that $f,h\text{ differentiable}\implies fh\text{ differentiable}$, just use induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{g(x+h)^n - g(x)^n}h=
\frac{g(x+h) - g(x)}h \left(g(x+h)^{n-1} + g(x+h)^{n-2}g(x)+\cdots
+ g(x)^{n-1}\right)
\\\to g'(x) \left(g(x)^{n-1} + g(x)^{n-1}+\cdots
+ g(x)^{n-1}\right) = ng'(x)g(x)^{n-1}
$$